# ggplot2 histogram scale_fill_gradient not working on continuous variable

Tags: r

I am having trouble getting a continuous variable to work on scale_fill_gradient using ggplot2 histograms. (I have a work around to convert the variable to factor and use scale_fill_manual and set them manually, thus I know my libraries and general ggplot structure is correct. This is my first example.) I've done everything according to the help text but it doesn't seem to be recognizing my fill at all in 2nd example.

```
 > str(data)

'data.frame':   506 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ value_A              : int  250000 219000 358000 340000 364000 295000 
 $ factor_B             : Factor w/ 6 levels "4","5","6","7",..: 4 3 4 4 4 3 
 $ numeric_C             : num  15.3 17.8 17.8 18.7 18
```

This works fine (it is on a factor variable):

```
ggplot(data, aes(value, fill = factor_B)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 30000) +  ...
  scale_fill_manual(values = ("#9db5bf", "#85a3b0","#6c90a0","#547e90", "#3b6b80","#235970"))
```

This does not work, it fills in the bars all in grey, nor do I get a legend of any kind: (this is on the numeric variable)

```
    ggplot(data, aes(value, fill = numeric_C)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 30000)  + ...
  scale_fill_gradient("some Ratio", low = "#9db5bf", high = "#235970")
```

Comment: I think I have the same problem, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(value, fill = numeric_C)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = ..count..), binwidth = 30000)  + # ...
  scale_fill_gradient("some Ratio", low = "#9db5bf", high = "#235970")
```